# How To Add Field In Registration Page

Tags: users

In user page, I want to add more field like username, contact number and address. What is the common way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use [Profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2), or you can add your fields in /admin/config/people/accounts/fields.

From Profile2 project page:

> Designed to be the successor of the core profile module, which is
>   [deprecated](https://www.drupal.org/node/874026) for Drupal 7. In
>   contrast to the deprecated module this module provides a new,
>   fieldable 'profile' entity - leverage the power of fields!

You can find out how to create profiles in [Profile2 documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1074296)